# REMOVE impex in distributed mode

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am trying to remove all carts from the database via impex , but when I executed the impex :

```
REMOVE Cart[batchmode=true];itemType(code)[unique=true]
;Cart
```

in Distributed mode the changes are not reflected in the database. Without distributed mode it works. How can I execute this impex to delete all the entries from the database in distributed mode?